# How to create a font alias if system doesn't support the font?

Tags: fonts, windows-10, alias, openvms, xming

Currently running a program in OpenVMS on a Vax machine and sending it to a Windows 10 PC running Xming.
I am having errors with the fonts. After research have found that the fonts I am having errors with are not supported on Xming (Type 1 fonts, which aren't even on the PC).
How would I go about directing the fonts that aren't supported to a font that is provided on the Windows 10 PC?

Comment: Anything useful at [Xming Fonts](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php), e.g. aliasing on the _server_, aka PC, side?